# How do I paint a texture onto an already textured object?

Tags: image, texture-painting

How do I paint a texture onto an already textured object? How do I do that? I have human with a skin texture and I want to paint a lip texture on his lips.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ZiQtohl3tmdUc0cnhuTmpqYjQ/view?usp=sharing

Heres the blend file.

Comment: Show us the texture.

Comment: Which texture? and just share the texture image?

Comment: Ill paint a texture onto the toenail of my person, then itll show up on the face, I erase it off the face and its gone from the toenails.

Comment: Sounds like UV overlapping. The toenail and face occupies the same UV space. Go into edit mode. Select all faces. In the menu to the right of the help menu at the top, select UV editing. Hit U and select "Smart UV project". No more overlapping. Now paint your toenail again.

Comment: I already did that. Still no luck. Any other things?

Comment: Also, the entire projection is within the texture. So that's not the problem either. The texture does not repeat at all because of this.

Comment: It also doesn't show up in the same place on render.

Comment: Ill paint on the face for lips. It shows up on the head. I said ok and tried rendering it to see if it would be an issue, it was even worse. It was near the torso.

Comment: A few screenshots of the model could help. Or even the blend.

Comment: I just have a few questions. first, do I have to add several uv maps? is that why I have issues? second, it's repeating the texture. how can I fix that? I have other questions but I'll save it because it's really overwhelming having all these issues at once

Comment: I posted the blend file in the question.

Comment: @AidanPallian having many questions is fine, just ask them on separate posts. This is not a forum but a questions and answers site.

Comment: Yes I know. I posted the blend. could someone take a look.

Comment: I want to paint lips onto the face for render

Answer (score 1):

### Repeated Image Mapping

The slot named Textures near the cursor in the Tool Tab is relative to the **Brush**

[image]

The slot in where you can choose which is the acticve texture to paint onto can be found in the Slot Tab in the **Slot** panel. The active texture is the one highlited with blue color.

[image]

As you can see on the right you are probably painting a texture with a brush that paint other textures, maybe sometime the same, and may be one of the causes you have repeating features spreading all around.

But the main cause of that relies on the **Repeating** settings of your Skin texture.

[image]

Those values alter how the texture is placed and sized on the UV space. You must set them to 1 an 1 to get the UV unwrapped island to stay in place.

If you want to paint just plain colors, remove Brush Texture by hitting the X button. If you want to paint texture from an image, be sure to use diffrent textures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So could you clarify.  what are the steps to paint lips onto the face?

Comment: Remove the Brush Texture, check on which slot you are painting on and than you should be ready to paint.

Comment: But the repeating? What causes it exactly? And how do I fix it? I'm sorry I didn't get it

Comment: Also, what if I wanted a texture?

Comment: What slot do I need to paint on? the skin?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question on the part about "repeating features". If you want a texture, you can use it in the Brush texture, but make sure to not paint on it..with it! I don't know on which texture you would like to paint the lips, you can choose freely.

Comment: Skin. But let me check your question again and get back to you

Comment: I already tried setting repeat to 1 since this answer unfortunately. nothing happened

Comment: I've added my .blendfile so you can test it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28851/discussion-between-carlo-and-aidan-pallian).